# Class Not Found in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have installed a fresh copy of zend framework 1.11.11 on my local workstation (Windows). For my admin module I have created "Login.php" form under /application/modules/admin/models/Form/Login.php I have also set up autoloader in Bootstrap.php Like

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
    {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');

        new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => 'Default')
        );

        $loader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/models/',
            'namespace' => '')
        );

        $loader->addResourceType('forms', 'Form/', 'Form');

        return $autoloader;
    }
```

on my loginAction() method of IndexController.php file of admin module,  i am using

```
$form = new Admin_Model_Form_Login();
```

But Getting below error:-

> Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_Form_Login' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\ztest\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php

Here is the code of Login.php

```
class Admin_Model_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->setAction('/admin/index/login')->setMethod('post');

        $account = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('account');
        $account->setLabel('Username')->setRequired(true);
        $account->setOrder(1);
        $this->addElement($account);

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password->setLabel('Password');
        $password->setOrder(2);
        $this->addElement($password);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('login');
        $submit->setLabel('Login');
        $submit->setOrder(3);
        $this->addElement($submit);
    }
}
```

Comment: provide code for /application/modules/admin/models/Form/Login.php

Comment: Have resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules" line in your application.ini. It can find your file in module dir. You should add module directory for auto load resources.

Comment: Your form should be named `Admin_Form_Login` shouldn't it?

Comment: @Asuraya: Yes, i have added that line of code in application.ini

Comment: @vascowhite : No, because Login.php is located at /application/modules/admin/models/Form/ folder

Comment: @RishiKalia: I have added code of login.php in my question above

Comment: Have you got a Bootstrap.php in your module path? (ie /application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php)?

Comment: And is the class definitely called "Admin_Model_Form_Login" within the file?

Comment: @williamvicary: Thank you very much for you correct response. Please add your comment as a Answer and i would like to upvote and accept it.. :) I forgot to add Bootstrap.php in admin module..

Comment: Glad I could help, added an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added a Bootstrap.php file to your module's path?

The file should be found in /application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php

Similar to this:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
     //Can be left blank
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add Bootstrap.php under admin module.